# self-referencing core data model for specific use case

Tags: core-data

I have seen other posts that self-referencing a core data entity is possible, but I feel my use case is a little different and I am having a hard time understanding how to wire things up.

I have a Person entity and I want to track 2 things:
- an array of Person entities whose profile the user "visited"
- an array of Person entities who have viewed "this" users profile

The inverse logic is making it hard to understand.

I have User A, User B.

If user A visits user B, the following relationships should be set up:
- User A's visited profiles shows User B.
- User B should see that user A visited him.

This is a To-Many relationship as things are "interesting" only when you know who you followed and who's following you... :-)

Am I making this more complex than it is? :-(

What I tried:

```
Person Entity
-visitedProfiles : inverse is viewedProfiles (To-Many relationship)
-viewedProfiles : inverse is visitedProfiles (To-Many relationship)

Result:  
 User A --> User B (user A visists user B)
 User A sees User B in BOTH (visitedProfiles and viewedProfiles) relationship.

Side-effect:
Also, regardless of how many profiles I visit, "visitedProfiles" and "viewedProfiles" always has only 1 item in the array (ie. the last profile I visited)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an especially complicated case. I personally find your choice of words a bit confusing, though. "viewedProfiles" and "visitedProfiles" don't sound like inverses of each other to me. How about "viewedProfiles" and "viewers" instead?

Regardless of the word choice, though, set up the relationships as you have described. If you add B to "viewers of A", then B's "viewedProfiles" will also be updated.

Your side effect of knowing the most recent view/visit takes a little extra work. You could use an ordered relationship for the viewers/viewees; that feels like the simplest thing to do. Or you could add a new entity, a Visit, which notes the viewer, the viewee, and the time/date of the visit. But that second approach is indeed more complicated.

Comment: Thank you, that naming convention makes it a lot easier to understand for me, as well.

Comment: Right, the 2nd case is what I was trying to achieve - ie, track certain metadata about a follow, but I stripped out all that code just to get the basic thing working. Also, I had a bug in my code that didn't push the change to the CD context. I will add the other metadata feature back later. I am going to mark this as accepted. Thank you again for the naming convention fix and for validating my assumptions as I was trying to fight Core Data too much :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of the relationships looks OK. You can call either

```
[a addVisitedProfilesObject:b];
```

or

```
[b addViewedProfilesObject:a];
```

to add `b` to `a.visitedProfiles` **and** `a` to `b.viewedProfiles`.

Comment: Thank you, that's how I had things setup. I had a bug in my own code which prevented the save. Your answer to: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447142/self-referencing-data-object-in-coredata was super helpful, as well.